# How does a keylogger respond when the user switches profiles

Tags: command-line, users, root

I'm wanting to log keystrokes on this ubuntu computer and I was wondering how a keylogger program responds when the user goes from a default user account and then logs in as root or vice versa.

For example consider the below activity. If the user issues all these commands will the keylogger still capture all activity even though the user is switching in and out of a different user account.

```
user@host> su #user logs in as root

password: ******** #user enters password

root@host> #user issues some commands

root@host> exit #user exits root and returns to default user

user@host> #user issues some commands
```